# Are these platform footings secure or should they be anchored into the concrete tube below?

Tags: deck, patio, footings

I recently installed a paver patio. Before installing the patio I poured two 12 inch concrete form tubes below where the footings were planned to be. So the pavers are sitting directly on top of the concrete pillar below. Should I have cut the pavers and attach the footing directly to the concrete tube or will a free floating footer be secure enough for this size platform?

Platform is 6x3 and sits about 3 foot from the ground. [image]

Comment: As long as you don't have tornadoes it should be okay.  Maybe a couple of angle braces so drunken linebackers don't knock them out.

Comment: Thanks that was my thought too. It's hard to see in the picture but the footings are bracketed and set about 10 inches in from the ends so it would be near impossible for someone to accidently kick one out.

Comment: I think you're OK from a structural standpoint, given that the deck part is only 3'-4' above the ground, and is fairly narrow.  Only thing I would be concerned about is the paver cracking or splitting under the post, at which point the post will try to settle down to the concrete base.

Comment: @SteveSh Good point, If I ever notice any cracking I can remove the paver below and replace the footing with one that goes all the way to the concrete.

Comment: Think you would be okay with pavers anyway with that small of a deck/landing.  If you have a pogo stick party on top might be different.  You have those pavers on top of cement footing, not something soft.